# How to get the return value of a block in an rspec stub?

Tags: rspec

say I have this code:

```
Lollercoaster.lmao { 'this is fun' }
```

...

How can I test the evaluation of that block?  In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
 expect(Lollercoaster).to have_received(:lmao).with('this is fun')
```

But that does not work obviously, as there's no argument being sent to the lmao method.

The docs show this as an example:

```
allow(dbl).to receive(:foo) { |&block| block.call(14) }
```

But when I try this, block is nil...

Comment: Please try my answer and let me know if that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out have_received does not work, but as the docs show, receive does work.

```
expect(Lollercoaster).to receive(:lmao) { |&block| expect(block.call).to eq 'this is fun' }
```

works.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
  expect(Lollercoaster).to receive(:lmao).with(key: value).and_return(return_value)
```

In your particular example, you should just need this (without `.with`):

```
  expect(Lollercoaster).to receive(:lmao).and_return(return_value)
```

Comment: This is not verifying the result of the value of the executed block...  Perhaps you did not understand my question.  I am trying to test the value of the block.  I basically need to do something like expect(block.call).to eq 'this is fun', but I am unable to get access to the block.